# How to get content from firebase database and send push notification to all users

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, push-notification

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSvbD.png)Hi i developing a app to send birthday notification to all app users.
The birthday data is stored in firebase
iam getting data from firebase and it sending push notification.
but it not sended to all app users

Comment: Show us the code you have tried and the database structure.

Comment: `[I developed … does this … but not that]` [What is your question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) By the end of a question body, the title is long forgotten.

Comment: i have posted photo of my database ,I have to get content and send push notificatioin to all users of my app using firebase

Comment: @MounishKumar have you solve the problem?